# Solving cumulative distribution function of Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability

100 coins flipped. What's the probability that there is less than 40 heads?

My solution: X is just a Binomial(100,0.5) and we need to find P(X<40) = $$\sum_{X=0}^{40} \binom {100}{X}(0.5)^X(0.5)^{100-X}$$ But whats the best way to calculate this? Or is there a better way to solve this question given that its an interview question?

Thanks

Comment: Try again: You're flipping 100 coins, so...

Comment: @SeanRoberson Edited. Sorry about that

Comment: Think Normal approximation.

Comment: Thats $P(X \leq 40)$, not $P(X < 40)$. You can try normal approximation or binomial tail bounds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds